# commitAnimations is not resizing my UIImageView subview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

I have created a UIView as a subview and to that subview I have added a UIImageView as a subview.

```
UIView *viewCreated;
UIButton *buttonCreated;
UIImageView *imageViewCreated;
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1024);
viewCreated = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
[viewCreated setTag:intTag];
viewCreated.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:viewCreated];
[self randomize];
UIImage *d1Image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", randomNumber]];
imageViewCreated = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,1024.0f, 1024.0f)];
[imageViewCreated setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", randomNumber]]]; 
[viewCreated addSubview:imageViewCreated];
//[imageViewCreated release];
return [viewCreated autorelease];
```

But when this code executes only the first subview is animated and resized.  The UiimageView moves 200 pixels to the left but does not get resized.

```
NSLog(@"sender tag %i",[sender tag]);   
UIView *currentView = [self.view viewWithTag:[sender tag]];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];  
currentView.frame = CGRectMake(-200, 0,40, 102);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I am pretty sure am I not creating the subviews correctly programmatically, because when I do it in Interface Builder it works as expected.

Do I have to do something specific to actually attach the behavior of the second subview to the first subview?

Comment: I might of missed something, but 1024 x 1024 seems like a very large UIView on an iPhone.

Comment: You are right.  I mis-tagged.  Should have been iPad.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this to resolve my problem.  Worked perfectly.

```
imageViewCreated.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Play with the `contentMode` property of the UIImageView. The default mode is `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`. Something like `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` may work better.
- Make sure somewhere in your code, you aren't accidentally setting the `autoresizesSubviews` property to NO.
- Instead of using frame sizing to scale the view, consider using the `transform` property and the `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` function. To make it move, you can also use `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It got me on the right track.

imageViewCreated.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;